# Как обновить html-страницу открытую через eel?

Tags: javascript, python, gui, ui, eel

Есть веб-интерфейс дружно работающий с модернизацией с помощью Js, Python.

В интерфейсе есть `<input>`, через который я передаю и обрабатываю информацию.

Ищу способ, метод при определённой команде в `<input>` обновить текущую страницу или вернуть определённый html-элемент.